# Sequence of fetches return out of order

Tags: javascript

Why does this code:

```
for (i in posts) {
            console.log(posts[i].pk)

            fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/${posts[i].pk}`)
                .then((resp) => resp.json())
                .then((data) => {

                    console.log(data)

                    var blogs = `
                        <div class = "center-div-row box-margin">
                                <div style="flex:2">
                                    <h5>${data.title}</h5>
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                                <div style="flex:1">
                                    <p>${data.body}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div style="flex:1">
                                    <p>${data.created}</p>
                                </div>
                                <button class="edit-btn">Edit</button>
                                <button>Delete</button>
                            </div>       
                    `
                    display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', blogs)

                })
                
        }
```

give me inconsistent API results? The data is displayed in different order and is just all out inconsistent. Any tips on how to make the fetch call better?

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistent? What is the actual behaviour and what is happening ? Could you please explain that?

Comment: It dosnt display the different items in a order, the order is inconsistent

Comment: You are calling API in loop , you dont know which call resolves first and which later , so there will be no order

Answer (score 0):

The fetch method is asynchronous, meaning your code will keep executing while it runs. There is no way to know how long the individual fetch calls will take and they don't all have to take the same amount of time. Therefore, they will complete at random times.

If you do as follows you will get an array of responses in a well-defined order.

If `posts` is an object (it's not clear from your code):

```
const pks = Object.values(posts).map(post => post.pk).sort()

const responses = await Promise.all(pks.map(pk => 
   fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/${pk}`)))
```

If `posts` is an array:

```
const pks = posts.map(post => post.pk)

const responses = await Promise.all(pks.map(pk => 
   fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blogs/${pk}`)))
```

Since the code uses the `await` keyword it needs to be run inside a function marked as `async`.